# Parse error.Primitives.RangeBase.Minimum

Tags: c#, slider, xamlparseexception, windows-8.1-universal

I'm trying to put a slider on a windows universal 8.1 and I'm uncertain what is needed. My error is:

```
Exception thrown: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in Mead Must Maker.Windows.exe
WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.Minimum'. [Line: 22 Position: 182]
The program '[1260] Mead Must Maker.Windows.exe' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
```

What exactly is going wrong with this code? This is line 22:

```
<Slider x:Name="volumeSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="50,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550" Maximum="10" LargeChange="1" Minimum="1" SmallChange="0.5" StepFrequency="0.5" TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="Outside" Value="5" FontFamily="Global User Interface" ValueChanged="volumeSlider_ValueChanged"/>
```

Here's the Event Handler:

```
private void volumeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        volume = float.Parse(volumeSlider.Value.ToString());
        volumeTextBox.Text = volume.ToString();
        Calculate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code. The following is your code from MainPage.xaml:

```
...Value="5" FontFamily="Global User Interface" ValueChanged="volumeSlider_ValueChanged"/>
```

In Slider control you set Value="5" and ValueChanged="volumeSlider_ValueChanged", notice that the code Value="5" will cause the function(volumeSlider_ValueChanged) to run immediately, but the Slider instance haven't been created at this moment. So if you debug your volumeSlider_ValueChanged function you can find the volumeSlider is null reference and it will cause a NullException. 
You can adjust you code like this:

```
private void volumeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (volumeSlider != null) {
                var volume = float.Parse(volumeSlider.Value.ToString());
                volumeTextBox.Text = volume.ToString();
            }
        }
```